# My show function in my controller is not finding the creator of an Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have part of a rails application where a user will create a recipe that will be saved in their "cookbook". Other users will be able to take recipes from other users. So there will be an aspect in the application that shows who created the recipe.

**Schema for a Recipe**

```
create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "recipe_name"
 t.string "description"
 t.integer "calories"
 t.integer "carbs"
 t.integer "fats"
 t.integer "protein"
 t.integer "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Where I am having trouble is displaying the recipe's creator.

```
  def show
   @user = current_user
   @recipe = Recipe.find_by(params[:id])
   creator = User.find_by(params[@recipe.user_id])
   @creator = creator.first_name
  end
```

So for right now I have two user's John (Id: 1) and Alex (Id:2). When I have Alex make a recipe and I put a pry under @recipe I get a user_id of 2 when I call @recipe.user_id.

However, when I put the pry under creator and call creator I get the user_id of 1 and I get John. I believe something is wrong with how I am trying to find the user using the user_id in @recipe. I was wondering if anyone know what I am doing wrong or if I need to add more information. Thanks.

Comment: `params[@recipe.user_id]` that seems really suspect; also, you could create a `belongs_to :user` in the `Recipe` model and then just `@creator = @recipe.user.first_name`

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
User.find_by(params[@recipe.user_id])
```

Doesn't make sense for a couple of reasons:

- `find_by` expects a hash-like structure. Something like: `User.find_by(id: xxx)`
- `params[@recipe.user_id]` doesn't make sense because that's going to be something like: `params[1]` which is not what you want.

This:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find_by(params[:id])
```

Also suffers from the malformed `find_by`.

So, try something like:

```
def show
  @user = current_user
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  creator = @recipe.user
  @creator = creator.first_name
end
```

This, naturally, assumes you have your association between `Receipt` and `User` set up correctly (i.e., using `belongs_to`).